# Send attachment/Download file from Symfony action

Tags: php, http-headers, symfony-1.4, download, attachment

I'm trying to deliver a CSV file through an action. The mime-type in the response still shows as text/html. Can someone help? Thanks

```
        //$this->setLayout(false);
        //$this->getUser()->shutdown();
        //sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);
        $response = $this->getContext()->getResponse();
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->clearHttpHeaders();
        $response->setHttpheader('Pragma: public', true);
        $response->addCacheControlHttpHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
        $response->setContentType('application/octet-stream', true);
        $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true);
        $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file_path));
        $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
        $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
        //$response->setContent(file_get_contents($file_path));
        //readfile($file_path);
        $this->renderText(file_get_contents($file_path));
        //return sfView::NONE;

        return sfView::HEADER_ONLY;
```

Trust me, before getting here, I've all search results purple. As you can see all the permutations & combinations above, I still couldn't get this working!

Comment: This overdoes it a little -- the HEADER_ONLY and sendHttpHeaders should not be needed, but the rest is a good overview of what it takes to serve like a static file server would.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
$path = 'absolute/path/to/the/file';

/** @var $response sfWebResponse */
$response = $this->getResponse();

$response->setContentType('text/csv');
$response->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($path));

return sfView::NONE;
```

**Note:** filename must be ASCII see [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3)